# Cannot unpair YouTube app on my smartphone from LGTV (SmartTV)

Tags: youtube, smart-tv

I cannot unpair my Android smartphone YouTube app from my LGTV.

**On LGTV:** I went on YouTube app and log-off my account. I also disconnected all mobile devices from it, what should (?) suffice in case my cell phone is stolen or something else happens, but...

**On Phone:** I cleared all app data and cache for YouTube app. But still, after starting the YouTube app, my LGTV is still registered *and* I can make YouTube videos play on LGTV.

**On YouTube account:** I removed the LGTV from YouTube configuration, but still any account on the phone can make videos play on the LGTV.

There is something that is being left on my smartphone that still allows it to control the LGTV.

The next step (that I am holding) is: completely reset my phone and research some way to completely reset my LGTV (if it makes any difference).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a TV paired with my YouTube account, so this is really just another setting to look at.

1. Go to your YouTube account: https://www.youtube.com/account
2. Click on the **Connected TVs** option at the bottom of the left hand menu.
3. If available, disconnect the TV from here.

Comment: I went there, I had already removed the TV; interestingly is that I can make the youtube app play on LGTV from any account I have registered on the phone, even account that has not linked to the LGTV before! :(

Comment: Maybe you could perform a factory reset on the TV? I was looking online but without knowing what TV you have, I couldn't find a generic enough tutorial.

Comment: that may be a workaround so I could take care of it from the LGTV what is the right way to do it; anyway I may be forced to to clean the phone from this abusive/excessive data storage that I cannot easly remove; if I knew where such information is stored I would one step do clean it up :)